# How to handle HOLD projects in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Below are the stages of my Opportunity in the Salesforce system.

- Identified
- Qualified
- Specified
- Proposal
- Follow Up
- Close

I need to mark my opportunities which are on HOLD. I felt adding HOLD as a stage is not a good idea as at any point Opportunity can go on hold. Is there some other way to mark projects which are on hold? I am new to Salesforce. Please help.

Thanks
Niki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "HOLD" is a truly state of your opportunity there is no problem to create this new Status value. Otherwise, if you're not comfortable with this approach, you can create a new Checkbox field named "On Hold". If you decide for this approach, considerer one of the bellow:

1. create a validation rule to avoid change the Opportunity Status while the opportunity "On Hold" checkbox is selected or;
2. create a workflow (or Process Builder) to assign Unchecked (false) to "On Hold" field always the opportunity status is changed.